# How to add multiple empty columns to a PySpark Dataframe at specific locations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried researching for this a lot but I am unable to find a way to execute and add multiple columns to a PySpark Dataframe at specific positions.

I have the dataframe that looks like this:

```
Customer_id   First_Name   Last_Name
```

I want to add 3 empty columns at 3 different positions and my final resulting dataframe needs to look like this:

`Customer_id   Address  First_Name   Email_address  Last_Name   Phone_no`

Is there an easy way around it, like the way you can do with `reindex` on python?

Comment: What has `reindex` to do with the order of columns? Check [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) here. As I understand, you want to add three columns and in this order `Customer_id   Address  First_Name   Email_address  Last_Name   Phone_no`, right?

Comment: Yes! I mean with `reindex`, I could just define all the columns including the ones I wanted to create and just put them in the necessary order.

Comment: That's fine. But with `reindex` you reorder the rows and not columns - just to put things into perspective.  Reindexing has a definition in Python and it is not what you are asking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```python
# Creating a DataFrame.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [('1','Moritz','Schulz'),('2','Sandra','Schröder')],
     ('Customer_id','First_Name','Last_Name')
)
df.show()
+-----------+----------+---------+
|Customer_id|First_Name|Last_Name|
+-----------+----------+---------+
|          1|    Moritz|   Schulz|
|          2|    Sandra| Schröder|
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

You can use [lit()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) function to add empty columns and once created you can use SQL's `select` to reorder the columns in the order you wish.

```python
df = df.withColumn('Address',lit(''))\
       .withColumn('Email_address',lit(''))\
       .withColumn('Phone_no',lit(''))\
       .select( 
           'Customer_id', 'Address', 'First_Name',
           'Email_address', 'Last_Name', 'Phone_no'
       )
df.show()
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
|Customer_id|Address|First_Name|Email_address|Last_Name|Phone_no|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
|          1|       |    Moritz|             |   Schulz|        |
|          2|       |    Sandra|             | Schröder|        |
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
```

As suggested by user @Pault, a more concise & succinct way -

```python
df = df.select(
    "Customer_id", lit('').alias("Address"), "First_Name",
    lit("").alias("Email_address"), "Last_Name", lit("").alias("Phone_no")
)
df.show()
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
|Customer_id|Address|First_Name|Email_address|Last_Name|Phone_no|
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
|          1|       |    Moritz|             |   Schulz|        |
|          2|       |    Sandra|             | Schröder|        |
+-----------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I just did the same thing... just that I did the select statement separately! I mean on a new dataframe after generating all the columns with `withColumns`

Comment: There's no need for the `withColumn`s here- you can just use `select`: `df = df.select("Customer_id", lit('').alias("Address"), "First_Name", lit("").alias("Email_address"), "Last_Name", lit("").alias("Phone_no"))`

Answer (score 7):

If you want even more succinct, that I feel shorter :

```
for col in ["mycol1", "mycol2", "mycol3", "mycol4", "mycol5", "mycol6"]:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
```

You can then select the same array for the order.

(edit) Note : withColumn in a for loop is usually quite slow. Don't do that for a high number of columns and prefer a select statement, like :

```
select_statement = []
for col in ["mycol1", "mycol2", "mycol3", "mycol4", "mycol5", "mycol6"]:
    select_statement.append(F.lit(None).alias(col))
df = df.select(*df.columns, *select_statement)
```